# If two analytic functions agree on a disk in their domain $D$, then they are equal in $D$?

Tags: complex-analysis

If two analytic functions $f,g$ agree on a disk $D_0$ in their (open, connected) domain $D$, then $f = g$ in all of $D$?

My attempt at a sketch proof: For any $z \in D$, there is a path from the center of $D_0$ to $z$. Take a point $z_1 \in D_0$ on the path and consider a disk $D_1$ in $D$ centered at $z_1$. $f$ and $g$ are represented by the same power series in $D_1$ as they are in $D_0$, and so must also agree. Repeat this argument, taking points and constructing disks along the path until we reach $z$.

I have two questions: **1)** Is my reasoning correct?

**2)** Is this is a "named" result? I have been using "Complex Made Simple" by Ullrich, and it doesn't seem to be in the first few chapters (0 to 4). I am hoping to read more about it, and see a full proof if possible.

Comment: Essential theorem: if $f$ and $g$ are analytic and agree on a set which has an accumulation point in the domain, then $f=g$.  Agreeing on a convergent sequence suffices.  Is this a result you're not supposed to have (and thus use) here?

Comment: (1) It's not at all clear to me why you will eventually reach $z$; maybe the disks get smaller and smaller and you get stuck somewhere. In fact one can certainly construct domains where this happens, for some paths at least. (2) "Uniqueness of analytic continuation" is a name used for the phenomenon you're proving.

Comment: [Zeros of analytic functions are isolated](http://planetmath.org/zeroesofanalyticfunctionsareisolated).  And @GregMartin: The path is compact so finitely many disks suffice.

Comment: @NateEldredge: if $D$ is the complex plane minus the negative real numbers, and the path goes through $0$, then you can't get from the lower half-plane to the upper half-plane using open disks. So there has to be some assumption on the path + domain, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for 2), this is often called the "Identity theorem". I think your idea is in the right direction; however, this is usually proven by showing that the equalizer of $f$ and $g$ is both open and closed, hence all of $D$ (as $D$ is connected).

Comment: This is indeed the Identity theorem. Thanks!